# Draw New Path beneath Overlay Image

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

When I draw a new path in fabric.js `isDrawingMode: true` (right side of the screenshot) I want it to appear beneath my overlay image, that is a transparent png.

[image]

```js
        var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
            isDrawingMode: true,
            preserveObjectStacking: true
        });


        var img = fabric.Image.fromURL(imgUrl, function(oImg) {
            oImg.scaleToWidth(canvas.getWidth());
            oImg.id="OverlayImage";
            canvas.setOverlayImage(oImg, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
        });
```

It works as soon as I finish the path, though.

I experimented with multiply filter, and stacking order on mouse move event, but got nowhere.

Any idea how to solve this!

https://codepen.io/localhorst/pen/zYvKWqo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a 100% fabric solution would imply not to use the fabric brush/freeDrawingMod.
you could create your draw path and add it to the canvas as a fabric object by tracking mousedown and mousemove, updating your fabric path object each mousmove. 
There is a nice explanation for creating a path object at the end of the page : http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1

Simpler solution would be to set the image as a html element positioned on top of the canvas. with pointer-events disabled on the image you could click through and draw on the fabric canvas.

from your codepen:

```html
<div class="row">
    <img class="overlay" src="https://sandmoshi.github.io/eColorBook/pages/fox-trans.png"/>
    <div class="col-8">
            <canvas id="c" height="600" width="800" style="border:1px solid #aaa;"></canvas>
        </div>
...
```

```css
.overlay{
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  -khtml-user-drag: none;
  -moz-user-drag: none;
  -o-user-drag: none;
  user-drag: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

i have forked your pen to demonstrate : https://codepen.io/TheNils/pen/QWjdEOR

Comment: is this https://codingsans.com/blog/fabricjs-tutorial#FreeHand_Drawing what you mean in your first option?

The CSS Overlay is so freaking clever! Thanks!

Comment: yes , that way you could control the z-offset of the path at anytime